# Every matrix can be written as a sum of unitary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

> Any matrix $A \in \mbox{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$ can be written as a finite linear combination of elements $U_i\in U(n)$:
>
> $$ A = \sum_{i} \lambda_i U_i$$

Is this true? How could I prove it?

Comment: Are the $\lambda_i$ complex or real numbers ?

Comment: I guess complex, but it's not clear in the paper, where this is stated

Comment: @CaptainLama how do you figure?

Comment: Ah, no, nevermind, the argument I had in mind is actually false...

Comment: At least if the eigenvectors are lineally independent the sentence is true. You can use the own eigenvectors of A to build the unitary matrices $U_i$, playing with the eigenvalues and the $\lambda_i$ to obtain the proper eigenvalues of $A$. However, it is not clear for me what does it happens when some of the eigenvectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reference to the MathOverflow question is a good one. If $A$ is a complex matrix, you can normalize so that $\|A\| \le 1$. Then
$$
                 A = B + iC
$$
where $B$, $C$ are selfadjoint and given by
$$
               B = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^{\star}),\;\;\; C=\frac{1}{2i}(A-A^{\star}).
$$
These selfadjoint operators also satisfy $\|B\| \le 1$ and $\|C\|\le 1$, which means that their eigenvalues--which must be real--are in $[-1,1]$. Then you can decompose $B$ and $C$ as
$$
         B = \frac{1}{2}(U_{B}+V_{B}),\;\;\; C=\frac{1}{2}(U_{C}+V_{C})
$$
where $U_{B}, V_{B}, U_{C}, V_{C}$ are unitary and given by
$$
           U_{B} = B + i\sqrt{I-B^2},\;\; V_{B}=B-i\sqrt{I-B^2} \\
           U_{C} = C + i\sqrt{I-C^2},\;\; V_{C}=C-i\sqrt{I-C^2}
$$
This makes sense becaue $I-B^2$ and $I-C^2$ are selfadjoint with their eigenvalues in $[0,1]$; so the square roots are defined that also have eigenvalues in $[0,1]$. You can check that
$$
     U_{B}U_{B}^{\star}= U_{B}^{\star}U_{B} = (B-i\sqrt{I-B^2})(B+i\sqrt{I-B^2})=B^2+(I-B^2)=I.
$$
Then $\frac{1}{2}(U_{B}+V_{B})=B$, $\frac{1}{2}(U_{C}+V_{C})=C$ and $A=B+iC$ is a linear combination of unitary matrices.

Comment: looks good, thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: @john : You're welcome. I made a couple of minor corrections where I dropped a factor of $2$, but that does not affect the final result.

Comment: It is maybe worth noting that, as $B$ and $C$ are Hermitian, $U_B = V_B^\dagger$ and $U_C = V_C^\dagger$. $A$ is thus actually decomposed into just two genuinely different unitary matrices and their respective adjoints.

Answer (score 12):

It is known that every complex square matrix $A$ can be written as a linear combination of at most **two** unitary matrices. First, by scaling, you may assume that $\|A\|\le1$. Then, by singular value decomposition, you may also assume that
$$
A=\operatorname{diag}(s_1,\ldots,s_n)
$$
where the singular values $s_j$s are real nonnegative and bounded above by $1$. Now, as $s_j=\frac12(z_j+\bar{z}_j)$, where $z_j=s_j+i\sqrt{1-s_j^2}$ has unit modulus, it follows that $A$ is the average of two unitary matrices.

If I remember correctly, there was also an open conjecture that the least possible number $k(n)$ such that every real $n\times n$ matrix can be written as a linear combination of at most $k(n)$ real orthogonal matrices is equal to $4$. It has been shown that $k(n)\le 4$. See proposition 1 in Chi-Kwong Li and Edward Poon, *Additive Decomposition of Real Matrices*, Linear and Multilinear Algebra, 50(4):321-326, 2002.

Comment: May I ask why $z_j$ is constructed as such a form?

Comment: @Charmbracelet Every nonnegative real number $s_j\in[0,1]$ is the real part of some complex number $z_j$ on the unit circle.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see an elementary linear algebra proof right now, but an answer is given at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85994/sums-of-unitary-matrices), namely that in a $C^*$-algebra, any operator is the linear combination of four unitary operators. The algebra $M(n, \mathbb{C})$ of $n × n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ becomes a $C^*$-algebra if we consider matrices as operators on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{C}^n$, and use the operator norm $||.||$ on matrices.