# Every linear transformation can be decomposed in sum of unitary operators

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ an unitary space and $T: V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation. 
Find $U_1$ and $U_2$ unitary transformations such that $T= U_1 + iU_2$.

I think is related with this 
 analogous [question in matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710247/every-matrix-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-unitary-matrices)  but I am clueless how to reduce it in two operators.

How could I prove it?

Comment: This can't be true. Take $v\mapsto 3v$.

Answer (score 0):

Let T, K and L be linear transformations such that 
K = 1/2(T'+T) and L = (1/2)(1/i)(T'-T) where T' is the adjoint of T.
and see that T = K+iL