# Given a set of unitary matrices, can one find a vector whose images under these unitary matrices span the underlying Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Given a set of (linearly independent) $d\times d$ complex unitary matrices $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n \subseteq M_d$ with $n\geq d$, does there exist a vector $v\in \mathbb{C}^d$ such that $$\text{span} \{U_1v, U_2v, \ldots , U_nv\} = \mathbb{C}^d ?$$

The motivation for this question comes from the theory of mixed unitary quantum channels. A *quantum channel* $\Phi: M_d \rightarrow M_d$ is a completely positive and trace preserving linear map. Any such map admits a Kraus representation of the form $\Phi (X) = \sum_{i=1}^k A_i X A_i^*$, where $\{A_i \}_{i=1}^k \subseteq M_d$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k A_i^* A_i = \mathbb{I}_d$. We say that a quantum channel is *mixed unitary* if it can be expressed as a convex combination of unitary conjugations: $\Phi (X) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i U_i X U_i^*$. Our aim then is to look for a rank one input projector $X = vv^*$ for some $v\in \mathbb{C}^d$ such that the output $\Phi (vv^*) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i (U_i v) (U_i v)^*$ has full rank. This is possible only if $n\geq d$. To avoid trivial counterexamples, we can also assume that $\{ U_i\}_{i=1}^n \subseteq M_d$ is linearly independent.

**Follow-up question:** Since it has been shown below that the question can be answered in the negative for $d\geq 4$, the natural way of progression would be to ask if one can provide a classification of all the sets of (linearly independent) unitary matrices $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n \subseteq M_d$ which allow for the existence of $v\in \mathbb{C}^d$ such that $$\text{span}\{U_1v, U_2v, \ldots ,U_nv\}=\mathbb{C}^d.$$
One can also try to answer this question for (linearly independent) sets of arbitrary complex matrices: $\{ A_i \}_{i=1}^k \subseteq M_d$.

Comment: The answer is obviously no, if $U_k = e^{it_k}\,I$ with distinct $t_k$. So, would you like these matrices to be linearly independent, for example?

Comment: @amsmath Yes I've now added this additional assumption in the question. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Proof for $d=2$: Assume the two standard basis vectors do not work as $v$. Then $U_1 = [u,v]$ and $U_2 = [su,tv]$ with $s,t\in\mathbb C$, $|s|=|t|=1$. Now, choose a vector $x$ with non-zero entries. Then$$\alpha U_1x + \beta U_2x = \alpha(x_1u + x_2v) + \beta(x_1 su + x_2 tv) = (\alpha + s\beta)x_1u + (\alpha + t\beta)x_2v.$$ Since $u\perp v$, this implies $\alpha + s\beta = \alpha + t\beta = 0$, which is only possible for $(\alpha,\beta)\neq (0,0)$ if $s=t$. But then $U_2 = tU_1$, contradiction!

Comment: Does it matter that $M_d$ is a $d^2$-dimensional space, yet you're using as few as $d$ matrices? It seems like there is a high chance of a set of $d$ LI matrices *not* yielding $d$ LI images for any $v$.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry Yes, I think so too. That is why I've included the number $n\geq d$ itself as a parameter when I ask for a classification of sets of matrices $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ which allow the desired vector to exist. If $n$ is close to $d$, then we should expect that our requirement imposes severe constraints on the sets of allowed matrices. If $n> d^2-d$ for instance, the answer by Daniel below shows that the desired vector exists irrespective of what kind of matrices are present in the set!

Comment: I seem to remember this question had a bounty about a week ago.  Can anybody explain what has happened to it?  It hasn't been awarded to any one of the answers below.

Answer (score 5):

For $d\geq 4$ the answer is no.   To see why, let $k=d-2$, so that $k\geq 2$.

By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1710390/728080) every complex $k\times k$ matrix can be written as a linear combination of four unitary matrices.  As a consequence, we
see that
the unitary group $\mathscr U(k)$  spans $M_k(\mathbb C)$, so it is certainly possible to find a linear independent set formed by $k^2$
unitary $k\times k$ matrices, say $\{U_i\}_{1\leq i\leq k^2}$.  Now consider the linearly independent set
$$
  \{I_2\oplus U_i:1\leq i\leq k^2\}\subseteq \mathscr U(k+2) = \mathscr U(d),
  \tag 1
  $$
where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

Given any
$$
  x=(x_1,  x_2,  \ldots , x_{k+2})\in \mathbb C^{k+2} = \mathbb C^d,
  $$
notice that every vector of the form
$$
  (I_2\oplus U_i)x
  $$
is orthogonal to
$$
  y: = (\overline{x_2},  -\overline{x_1},  0,  0,  \cdots ,  0)
  $$
so the set $\{(I_2\oplus U_i)(x):1\leq i\leq k^2\}$ cannot span $\mathbb C^d$.

As pointed out by @amsmath, if $x_1=x_2=0$, we need to argue instead that the vectors $(I_2\oplus U_i)x$ have vanishing first two coordinates, hence cannot span $\mathbb C^d$ either.

Since $k\geq 2$, we have that
$$
  k^2 \geq  k+2 = d,
  $$
so the set in (1) is a linearly independent set with (precisely $k^2$,  and hence) at least $d$ unitary $d\times d$ matrices,  but there is no vector $x$
such that the images of $x$ under our matrices span $\mathbb C^d$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120330/discussion-on-answer-by-ruy-given-a-set-of-unitary-matrices-can-one-find-a-vect).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple necessary and sufficient condition for the absence of such $v$.

Let $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ be linearly independent $d\times d$ matrices. Define the completely positive map $T(X)=\sum_{i=1}^nA_iXA_i^*$.

Now, let $u=\sum_{i=1}^de_i\otimes e_i$, where $e_1,\ldots,e_d$ stands for the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^d$.

It is not hard to prove that for every $A,B\in M_{d\times d}$, $$tr(A\otimes B\  uu^*)=tr(AB^t).$$

Thus, we have the following equivalent conditions:

1. $tr(T(vv^*)ww^*)=0$
2. $tr((T(vv^*)\otimes \overline{w}w^t) uu^*)=0$
3. $tr((vv^*\otimes \overline{w}w^t)B)=0$, where $B$ is the non-normalized state $B=T^*(\cdot)\otimes id (uu^*) $.

Since $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are linearly independent, $\operatorname{rank}{B}=n$.

So the absence of such $v$ is equivalent to the fact that for every $v\in\mathbb{C}^d$ there is a vector $w\in \mathbb{C}^d\setminus\{\vec{0}\}$ such that $v\otimes w\in \ker(B)$.

In particular, it implies that $\operatorname{rank}(B)\leq d^2-d$, since there are at least $d$ linearly independent product vectors in its kernel.

Therefore, if the number of matrices above, $n$, is greater than $d^2-d$ then there exists such $v$.

Comment: Very interesting! But, if I understand your answer correctly, the condition $n\leq d^2 -d$ is just a _necessary_ one implied by the absence of such a $v$. I mean this is not sufficient right because even if $n\leq d^2 - d$, such a vector $v$ might exist for some special sets of matrices $\{A_i \}_{i=1}^n$. This is where the follow-up question above becomes important: For which such sets of matrices does the desired vector $v$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a set of $d$ unitary matrices $\{U_i \}_{i=1}^d \subseteq M_d$ for which the desired vector exists.

For each $i\in \{1,2,\ldots ,d \}$, we define $U_i$ to be the unitary shift matrix: $U_i e_k = e_{k+i}$, where the index addition happens modulo $d$ and $\{e_k \}_{k=1}^d$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^d$. Then, it should be clear that if we choose $v=e_1$ for instance, the set $\{U_i v \}_{i=1}^d$ is precisely the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^d$ and hence spans $\mathbb{C}^d$.