# If a hermitian matrix $\Sigma$ satisfy $A \Sigma A^{\dagger}=\Sigma$ where $A$ is unitary, is $\Sigma$ a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I numerically verified the case for the $2\times2$ matrix but don't know how to prove it theoretically. Let's say, if $\Sigma$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and we have $A \Sigma A^{\dagger}=\Sigma$, where $A$ is a unitary matrix, and $\Sigma$ is a Hermitian matrix, then does it imply $\Sigma$ also to be a diagonal matrix?

For clarification, $\Sigma$ is real in my case, but I don't know if 'real' really matters to prove $\Sigma$ is diagonal.

Here is a simple numerical verification for $2\times2$ case:
Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}, $$

which is a rotation matrix, let $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$, from the equation $A \Sigma A^{\dagger}=\Sigma$ we get $a=d, c=-b$, now hermitian implies $c=b$, so we get $c=b=0$ and prove $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Doesn't this always hold for $A = I$?

Comment: @Mason Yes when given $A = I$, we can't say $\Sigma$ is diagonal, probably I should add "for arbitrary unitary matrix $A$" in the description? I added a simple numerical verification for 2*2 case in my description.

Comment: Your "verification" is just an example of unitary $A$ for which your implication holds, but this is not true of *any* unitary $A$: Mason gave you a counterexample

Comment: Do you mean you intend to modify your question by requiring that $\Sigma$ commutes with *every* unitary matrix? But then the answer is obviously yes.

Comment: By the way, your example would still be wrong.

Comment: @AnneBauval can you give a proof why commutes with every unitary matrix imply a diagonal matrix? Or any sources?

Comment: @lcv Why you think it's wrong?

Comment: @dtouro Use the SVD to write $\Sigma = VDV^*$, with $V$ unitary and $D$ diagonal.

Comment: @dtouro Even if you let $[A(\theta),\Sigma] = 0, \,\, \forall \theta$ you only obtain $\Sigma = aI + b \sigma^y$ [as $A(\theta) = \exp(-i \theta \sigma^y)$]. Here $\sigma^y$ is the purely imaginary Pauli matrix.

Comment: @lcv Thanks I see your point, for $\Sigma$ in complex field, this example is wrong.

Comment: Yes, since you spoke of unitary I assumed a complex field.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial conjecture is trivially false, as Mason's counterexample $A=I$ shows.

Therefore, so is your "numerical verification for 2*2 case" (take $\theta=0$).

An answer to (a strengthening of) your modified question (in the comments) is the following: if an *arbitrary* (not necessarily hermitian) matrix $\Sigma\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ commutes with *every* unitary matrix $A\in U_n(\Bbb C),$ then $\Sigma$ is a [*scalar* matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Scalar_matrix). This is because [every complex $n\times n$ matrix is a linear combination of two unitary matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1710420/386889), and [if $\Sigma$ commutes with every complex $n\times n$ matrix, then it is scalar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, very clear.